# How can I implement a GWT callback url?

Tags: url, gwt, callback, oauth

I'm writing a GWT application that's going to use OAuth.  OAuth provides the ability to 'callback' to your website via a url that you pass into it along with an access key as part of the url parameters.

My question is this:  For a GWT application, how can I allow a custom URL to be pasted / redirected into the address bar?  Essentially it will be a server request which is dead simple using a tomcat server with jsp, but is there a way to handle this using a pure GWT implementation?

I can imagine the following is posible:

- Write a jsp page that is deployed with the GWT project
- Store the access key
- Redirect the user again to the main page of my GWT application

Is there a more pure way to do this with GWT?  Can I call directly into the RPC service to do this task?  If I call into the RPC service, am I supposed to redirect the user to a main page?  Can I just implement my GWT client side code so it recognizes custom parameters passed from the url?

What do you think is the best approach for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See com.google.gwt.user.client.Window.Location.replace(String newUrl), however the bad news is that you will lose all internal history.  Here is a blog entry of one person's [experiences with OAuth and his pure GWT solution](http://raibledesigns.com/rd/entry/implementing_oauth_with_gwt). Also there is a [GWT example project that does OAuth](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-examples/wiki/oAuth).

Comment: Those are both links to people trying to implement OAuth. I'm using scribe to do the OAuth for me, but I still need a custom handler for the authentication callback from the site.

Comment: So basically you want to handle the OAuth server-side using Scribe, so if I understand you correctly you need a few server-side methods.

1) A method that will create a request token and return the token to the client that will save the token and secret into a cookie. You will then redirect the client to the authentication page with the returned token.

When authenticated the callback URL will redirect the user to your site at which time a verifier will be available.  At this point you will send the verifier up to the server to create the access token.

Comment: The access token will then be returned to the client and stored in a cookie, at which point you can delete the request token cookie.  Now whenever the client makes a request to your server you will have access to the request token and can use scribe to make your requests.  The links provided above are pure GWT solutions, but if you want to use Scribe the method I just detailed should work.  Here is a link to a post that details how to do some of these steps with Scribe:

http://developer.linkedin.com/message/4568

Comment: It's working like a charm for now. I believe I will lose the history on the callback, once I implement history properly.

Answer (score 0):

I have also encountered with this problem. Here is my solution :

call RPC and

```
onSuccess() {
}

onFailure(){ // for example, don't have permission to see this page 
 Window.Location.assign("login.html");
}
```

You **can not** send redirect from rpc(servlet).