# Simple GWT OpenID Example

Tags: gwt, openid

I'm looking for a really simple GWT OpenID example, and haven't found one yet.  There have been some that are reasonable starts but miss little things like "verification" of the user.  I'd like to have a GWT app with RPC calls and this won't be a GAE based app, so the examples that rely on the built in auth for app engine unfortunately won't work.

Does anyone have any pointers?

Btw, it looks like I'll be using openid4java on the server side of the RPC.

Here are some of the tutorials I have found:

- http://armelnene.blogspot.com/2009/12/dummies-guide-to-gwt-and-openid-with.html
- (Easy if I were able to use GAE) http://code.google.com/appengine/articles/openid.html
- http://code.google.com/p/openid4java/wiki/SampleConsumer

Comment: hi.. i hav also tried all possible ways to implement openID in GWT. but i didnt succeed. Please share ur thoughts on implementing openID in GWT.

Answer (score 1):

See if my response here helps: [How can I implement a GWT callback url?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4499713)

Comment: Will be trying this tonight... things went sideways for a while. :(